# Ayuda con CSS3 y secciones

Tags: css3

compañeros,

Quisiera ayuda: Estoy realizando un proyecto y necesito que una tabla con información de una base de datos, se me repita con los mismos estilos, pero cada registro distinto, se me muestre uno debajo del otro.

Lo he intentado con el display:block y varias variantes de display, pero no se me modifica.

```
.padre{
   position:relative;
   display:block;
}
.hijos{
   position:relative;
}
```

El diseño de la tabla es así:

[image: Imagen 1]

Y necesito que me quede así:

[image: En bloques]

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: no se entiende la pregunta, por un lado primero dices que se repita con los mismo estilos y luego dices que cada registro distinto, trata de mostrar como esperas que se vea

Answer (score 0):

el asunto esta en donde agregas el estilo. puedes hacerlo con una tabla. le agregas el estilo al td y cada vez que salte de un tr a otro, se creara un nuevo recuadro como quieres.

Te hare un ejemplo

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery.getJSON demo</title>
  <style>
  .padre{
   padding: 40px;
    float: left;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 30px;
    background-color: lightblue;
    width:500px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
<tr><th>Nombres</th></tr>
<tr><td CLASS="padre">JUAN</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS="padre">PEPITO</td></tr>
<tr><td CLASS="padre">MARIA</td></tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Jonathan, mira, por favor [answer]. En este caso no se debería contestar la pregunta ya que el usuario (OP) no ha dado información suficiente por lo que es complicado dar una respuesta válida.